# Python in Atom, running Pygame, windows imminently closes

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, atom-editor

I've been having this problem within Atom or just executing the file via terminal (windows).

```
import pygame as py

py.init()

win = py.display.set_mode((540, 680))

py.display.set_caption("Spacementar")
```

If i run the IDLE from python and execute it from there it runs and stays open, but atom or cmd, this only happens with UI modules (Tkinter and Pygame), text stays.

Answer (score 0):

That the window stays open in IDLE is a problem with tkinter, it should actually close immediately because the program is done after the last line, the Python interpreter shuts down and calls [`pygame.quit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit).

If you want to keep the window open, you can use a `while` loop in which you handle the events, game logic and drawing and finally update the display with `pygame.display.flip`.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pygame.Color('gray12')

done = False
while not done:
    # Handle the events.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # If the 'x' button of the window gets clicked.
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                print('mouse button pressed')

    # Insert game logic here.

    # Draw everything.
    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    # Flip the display buffer.
    pygame.display.flip()
    # Limit the frame rate to 60 FPS.
    clock.tick(60)

# This `pygame.quit` call is only needed to close the window in IDLE.
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Just to clarify my doubt, so it's normal for Atom, Sublime, and CMD to close the Tkinter and PyGame when it finishes reading the code? Since the Python IDLE doesn't do that

Comment: Another question since tried your code and added another line out of curiosity under the elif:
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 2:
                print('right button')
it's the event,button == 2 , the number it's the mouse mapping? since when I added that nothing happened; or it's 1 or 0 like a Boolean?

Comment: *"Just to clarify my doubt, so it's normal for Atom, Sublime, and CMD to close the Tkinter and PyGame when it finishes reading the code?"* Yes, that's normal for pygame. Tkinter works differently, since it got its own main loop that is hidden from you and keeps running until you tell it to quit.

Comment: `event.button` is a special attribute of `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` and `MOUSEBUTTONUP` events. `1` means left mouse button, `2` middle mouse, `3` right mouse, `4` mouse wheel up and `5` mouse wheel down. Add more `elif event.button ==` clauses in the same `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` clause to test them.